# react native : What is the correct way to display a particular item from the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is the correct way to display a particular item from the next object?
If i want display only the `"Sampling_Request_ID"` so how i display it ?

```
const { selectedItems } = params;

{
  "selectedItems": {
    "3099047": {
      "Consumer_Name": "",
      "Facility_Name": "dor",
      "Lab_Site_Name": "lab",
      "Parameters_Bundle_Name": "12",
      "Sampling_Due_Date": "01/10/2020",
      "Sampling_Frequency_Name": "ubi",
      "Sampling_Instructions": "5541",
      "Sampling_Request_ID": 3099047,
      "Water_Source_Code": "1",
      "Water_Source_Name": "gog"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
const object = {"selectedItems": {"3099047": {"Consumer_Name": "", "Facility_Name": "dor", "Lab_Site_Name": "lab", "Parameters_Bundle_Name": "12", "Sampling_Due_Date": "01/10/2020", "Samplin
g_Frequency_Name": "ubi", "Sampling_Instructions": "5541", "Sampling_Request_ID": 3099047, "Water_Source_Code": "1", "
Water_Source_Name": "gog"}}};

const result = object.selectedItems["3099047"].Water_Source_Name;
```

result will have "gog" value

Comment: i edit my question, if now i want to display the "Water_Source_Name" ? how i do it

Comment: do u have facebook or something i can contact with u ?

Comment: Facebook : https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004540366719

Comment: @shira you can ask here if you want

Comment: i need u see my code coz something not works well there coz that .

Comment: its not let me do "const result = object.selectedItems.3099047.Water_Source_Name;" the "3099047" is bad for this and makes error